# Django ORM Nested Model

Tags: sql, django, orm

I'd like to store a django orm model which should look like the json below.
Any ideas how to achieve this without using relations and different models? I also need to query these fields a lot.

```
{
    id: 123,
    title: 'foo',
    duration: {
        min: 10,
        max: 20,
        days: 14
    },
    activities: {
        sport: {
            weight: 2,
            note: 'foobar'
        },
        food: {
            weight: 3,
            note: 'meh'
        },
        ... (always 6 more)
   }
}
```

Comment: Please inline your data.  Don't make people go elsewhere to see what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [django-jsonfield](https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield) to hold arbitrary looking data.

[django-pgfields](http://django-pgfields.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html) add nested datastructures that you can do ORM lookups on.

Comment: I already considered it, but I need to query these fields a lot.

Comment: Have you modeled it using relations and it is too heavy?

Comment: Exactly. It just feels wrong to me. The json data above is just about 1/4 of the whole model, the other 3/4 have the same problem.

Comment: This is not a large model relation thou.  What's your backend?  Did you try putting indexes on the proper fields?  Did you use select_related/prefetch related?